# RoR: Param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error when I try to update a prop(which is like an article). I can create a prop but when I go to edit it I get the following error:

[image]

This is my props controller:

class PropsController < ApplicationController
      attr_accessor :user, :answer, :choice, :prop

```
  def index
    @props=Prop.all
  end

  def show
    @prop = Prop.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @prop = Prop.new
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

  end

  def edit
    @prop = Prop.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @answer = @user.answers.update(prop_params)


  end

  def create
    @prop = Prop.new(prop_params)
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

    @answer = Answer.new

    if @prop.save
    redirect_to @prop
    else
    render 'new'
    end

  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

    @prop = Prop.find(params[:prop_id])
    @answer = @user.answers.update(answer_params)

    if @prop.update(prop_params)
      redirect_to @prop
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

    if @answer.choice == @prop.choice
      puts "hello"
      @user.score += 7
      @user.save
    else
      @user.score -= 7
      @user.save

    end
  end

  def destroy
    @prop = Prop.find(params[:id])
    @prop.destroy

    redirect_to props_path
  end

  def select
    @prop = Prop.find(params[:choice])
  end

end

private
  def prop_params
    params.require(:prop).permit(:title, :text, :choice, :user_id, :id)
  end

  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:choice, :id, :prop_id, :user_id)
  end
```

This is my form. It is a partials shared between the new and edit views:

```
<%= form_for @prop do |f| %>

  <% if @prop.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@prop.errors.count, "error")  %>
prohibited this prop from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @prop.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|  %>
        <li><%= msg  %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>


  <%= f.radio_button(:choice, "A") %>
  <%= f.label(:choice, "The Correct Answer is A") %>
  <%= f.radio_button(:choice, "B") %>
  <%= f.label(:choice, "The Correct Answer is B") %>
  <%= f.radio_button(:choice, "C") %>
  <%= f.label(:choice, "The Answer Has Yet To Be Determined") %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You are using `@answer = @user.answers.update(prop_params)` in your edit action. The edit is there to load the given resource and use it to populate data in the form of your view. I guess it is not on purpose that you try to update your model inside the edit action, right?

Comment: It is on purpose. Only the admin can edit a prop- which is essentially a question. When the admin updates the answer, I update some records in the database.  Then all users who have the same answer have their score incremented.

Comment: Anyway -> prop_params require prop in your request parameters, if there are non given it will result in an error. I'm still not sure what's your goal but at you can either ensure that there is a params[:prop] always given or use a condition before the update like `if params[:prop].present?`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I ensure that there is a params[:prop] always given? Where do I put the code? Can you please provide some more detail?

Comment: The edit method of a resource controller only loads this resource, the changes applied happen in the update action. Therefor I'm not sure why you want to update the `Props` instance where it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your update action as:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @prop = Prop.find(params[:prop_id].merge(:user_id => @user))
    @answer = @user.answers.update(answer_params)

    if @prop.update(prop_params)
      redirect_to @prop
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

    if @answer.choice == @prop.choice
      puts "hello"
      @user.score += 7
      @user.save
    else
      @user.score -= 7
      @user.save

    end
  end
```

and your prop params as:

```
  def prop_params
    params.require(:prop).permit(:title, :text, :choice, :id)
  end
```

This helps in sending the user_id into the prop table by using merge method. Try this I hope this could resolve your issue and make sure you change your create action to send the user_id into prop table.